# Xcode: Build to Android (Is It Possible To Have A Compiler For Android In The Xcode IDE?)

Tags: android, xcode, compiler-construction, build, port

I've built my game in Objective-C using Cocos2d & Box2d, and have come to the realisation that everyone really does seem to have an android!

So I'm wondering how I can easily port to Android, and also have to ability to update my app without having to switch between IDE's?

What are people doing for this? What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [stackoverflow...android-applications-using-xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515360/create-android-applications-using-xcode)

Comment: have you tried googling? Maybe [this guys](https://www.apportable.com/solutions) can be of some use to you

Comment: Nope, this is not a duplicate since I am talking about Objective-c, not Java... Also Apportable is a paid solution, looking to do this natively, in house, and using the tools that are provided for free...